# ingress updated level from phone to browser?

Tags: ingress

I have been been playing ingress for a few days now, and my phone shows one of the sides of the octagon half-way of being full, but when I log in to the website, I still see the octagon on the upper left side of the screen as being empty. Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not doing anything wrong; just force-reload the website.

NB: I already reported that bug.